# Wrong implementation of function

Tags: calculus, functions

I implement a function `f` from screenshot:

```
function f(x) { return Math.sqrt(3 - 5 * x + Math.sqrt(x) + Math.cbrt(x)) / x - 1 }
```

But I've got a wrong answers for `x`, different than in screenshot. I can't find, where is my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Math.sqrt(x) + Math.cbrt(x)`

should be

`x*x + x*x*x`

Answer (score 1):

You're taking $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$ where you should be taking $x^2$ and $x^3$. (Also, I recommend putting parentheses around $x - 1$.)

Comment: And given the operator precedence in javascript, I am pretty sure the parenthesis is necessary. (+1)

Comment: @SangchulLee: haha, yes, that recommendation was not purely from an aesthetic point of view. Even in left to right languages (e.g. Smalltalk) the parentheses would be necessary. :-)